# dc.js setting y scale has not effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a project where I am attempting to implement a dc.js composite chart along with a bar chart and brush chart. The composite chart displays with a y scale from 0 - 50 but all of my data points fall within 49.5 - 50.25 so the line looks very flat. I would like to set the scale to my min/max data +/- 1. Here is the code I am using:

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);

var dim = cf.dimension(function (d) { return +d.trend; }),
    grp = dim.group().reduceCount(),
    min = dim.bottom(1)[0].trend,
    max = dim.top(1)[0].trend;

console.log(min); // min is 49.684
console.log(max); // max is 50.272

compositeChart.width(w)
  .height(h)
  ...
  .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]))
  ...
  .dimension(dim)
  .group(grp)
  .yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.format(',.1f)(d); });

dc.renderAll();
```

When the chart is rendered I still have a Y Axis scale from 0 - 50?? I also tried hard coding the min and max and it still does not change the scale..

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible you also have elasticY set true? I know of this bug: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/667 but am not aware of a 'bigger bug'. If this is such, please [report it](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new)!

Comment: Great suggestion, I did have `elasticY(true)`. And thanks for the link!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Generally you won't want to use elastic mode when you are setting the domain yourself, because it will override what you set - but here it has even worse consequences!